# Activity Not showing in friends ticker in custom open graph story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made open graph story on Facebook and it have approved and i have integrate it with facebook-sdk-v5 but story is not showing in user's friends ticker while it showing in user activities log.

please someone help me

Thank you

Comment: Not every story gets shown in newsfeed; as long as it shows up in the activity log, everything went fine from the technical point of view. The rest is up to Facebook.

Comment: @  CBroe, thanks for your reply But I have following things approved from facebook for my custom open story
App Details ,ACTION TYPES ,email, public_profile, 
publish_actions, user_friends, user_actions:{app_namespace}
and story are showing in the users activties but not any places.
is anything more i need to send for approval?
can you please help me so my custom open story will show in users friends ticker too?

Comment: is some one help me for that ?